# Java - IsAssignableFrom Paradox?

Tags: java

I have some third-party class. Its stripped-down (for the sake of brevity) functionality is as follows:

- Makes available two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` for external use. Each of these classes is completely unrelated to the other (meaning they don't share a common ancestor).
- Has a `handle()` function which accepts as input a object of type `Object`.
- The `handle()` function checks to see if the type of the object is either `ClassA` or `ClassB`.
- If the type matches, the code calls a user-defined function with the same object parameter.

Pseudo-code for the class and its usage is as follows:

```
// Third party code..

class ClassA implements InterfaceA { ... }
class ClassB { ... }

class WeirdCode {
    void registerUserMethod(func ...) { }
    void handle(Object input) { ... }
}


// My caller code..

function myHandler(T??? obj) {
    // Do something with obj
}

WeirdCode weirdCode = new WeirdCode(...);
weirdCode.registerUserMethod(myHandler);

weirdCode.handle(new ClassA(...));
```

Normally, the class is expected to be used exclusively for ONE type at a single time. So I can either use `ClassA` or `ClassB` but not both. However, if I want to handle both `ClassA` and `ClassB` objects, I have to do something like this:

```
// My caller code..

function myHandlerA(ClassA obj) { ... }
function myHandlerB(ClassB obj) { ... }

WeirdCode weirdCodeA = new WeirdCode(...);
WeirdCode weirdCodeB = new WeirdCode(...);

weirdCodeA.register(myHandlerA);
weirdCodeB.register(myHandlerB);

weirdCodeA.handle(new ClassA(...));
weirdCodeB.handle(new ClassB(...));
```

What I'd like is to be able to do the following:

```
// My caller code..

function myHandlerAB(Object obj) { ... }

WeirdCode weirdCode = new WeirdCode(...);

weirdCode.handle(new ClassA(...));
weirdCode.handle(new ClassB(...));
```

However if I do that, `WeirdCode` throws an exception cuz of the following code inside it:

```
void handle(Object obj) {
    ...
    if (ClassA.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getType())) {
        ...
        myHandler(obj);
    }
    else if (ClassB.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getType())) {
        ...
        myHandler(obj);
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    ...
}
```

The only thing I can control in this entire picture is the prototype of the `myHandler()` function. Is it possible to define a type such that both `ClassA` and `ClassB` are assignable from it, as well as both `ClassA` and `ClassB` to be cast-able to it? I think it isn't possible. But I'd love to be proven wrong cuz it'll help me solve my problem.

Comment: This problem seems to be solvable with the adaptor design pattern. Yet I do not understand why the `handle` method throws an exception. If your `myHandlerAB` does not throw an exception `myHandler` should not either (I assume that there is a register(myHandlerAB) missing, correct?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing I can control in this entire picture is the prototype
>   of the myHandler() function. Is it possible to define a type such that
>   both ClassA and ClassB are assignable from it, as well as both ClassA
>   and ClassB to be cast-able to it?

So what you want to do is:

```
MyType myType1 = new ClassA(...);
MyType myType2 = new ClassB(...);
```

and...

```
ClassA clsA = (ClassA) myType1;
ClassB clsB = (ClassB) myType2;
```

is that accurate?

Your Achilles' Heel here is that you do not control the types for ClassA and ClassB.  As I understand it, these objects are defined by third-party code which you are not able to modify.  It sounds like what you want to do is provide a form of limited multiple inheritance, which can be provided by interface inheritance.  However, since you don't control these classses, this solution isn't feasible.

Although the `instanceof` operator is much derided as a bane of good object-oriented software design, it is indispensable for situations like this in which you must interoperate with someone else's code.

FWIW, Java does not understand "prototypes" in the manner in which they are commonly understood (eg. prototypal inheritance as found in JavaScript).  You shouldn't try to force Java to understand prototypal inheritance.

Comment: that sucks.. im not as mad at java for not providing multiple inheritance as i am with the third party code for using `isAssignableFrom` operation.. well i guess i can forget about implementing a clean, generic solution and will have to resort to a dirty solution along more along the lines of copy-paste.. =/

Comment: Java gets more and more multiple inheritance as time goes by.  Prior to Java 8, the only sort of multiple inheritance was interface inheritance.  Java 8 introduces more multiple inheritance via the ability to provide default implementations in interfaces.  Overall, the decision to limit full multiple inheritance in Java was a good one.  It has probably prevented more problems than it has caused.